# DATE FORMAT in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my sample tables and the expected output and the corresponding query that I have return. I am running into DATE FORMAT ISSUES, When I try to get the Earliest date record from PROV table. Please Let me know if this is not clear

```
select *
from   beau_prov beau
       join provi prov
            on  trim(beau.no) = trim(prov.prov_no)
where  prov.ins_dt =
       ( select min(ins_dt)
         from   provi prov
         where  trim(beau.no) = trim(prov.no)
         and    beau.year = to_char(to_date(ins_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM', 'YYYY'), 'YYYY') )
```

BEAU

```
----------------------      
NAME |  NO    | YEAR |
----------------------
CAR  |  1234  | 2013 |
AUTO |  4356  | 2013 |
```

PROV

```
-----------------------------------------------     
NO   |NUMBER | NAME  | INS_DT                 |
-----------------------------------------------
1234 |  987  |  ZZ   | 7/13/2013 11:36:05 PM  | 
1234 |  456  |  ZZ   | 12/31/2013 10:34:45 PM |
```

RESULT

```
---------------------------------------
NAME |  NO    | YEAR |  NUMBER | NAME |
---------------------------------------
CAR  |  1234  | 2013 |  987    | ZZ   |
```

Comment: There are only twelve months in a year,. So it seems your source stores dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` and not the `dd/mm/yyyy` format your code uses. Although this only matters if the source is a string.

Comment: What is the TYPE of your PROV.INS_DT column? Ie, if you do `select data_type from user_tab_cols where column_name='INS_DT';`, what do you get?

Comment: What is the datatype of `BEAU.YEAR`? Also, you can't name a column `NUMBER`, and `RESULT` has two `NAME` columns. (Though as `RESULT` isn't used in your query anyway we can probably ignore it.) And is it `PROVI` or `PROV`?

Comment: Please provide definitions and sample data for the tables used in your query, which are called `BEAU_PROV` and `PROVI`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks William, I will provide definition and tables clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If `INS_DT` is an Oracle `date`, then you can just insert it into another `date` column as it is.

The formatting you are seeing is applied by the client application and is not part of the `date` value itself.

If it's supplied to your procedure as a string, then you would need to convert it to a `date` using `to_date(ins_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')`.

If `INS_DT` is an Oracle `date` and `BEAU_PROV.YEAR` is a string containing a 4-digit year, then you can join them using:

```
and beau.year = to_char(ins_dt,'YYYY')
```

Comment: From the source column, I have to take only YYYY to my results. In the example, 7/31/2013 11:36:04 PM. I have to populate 2013 in my results. And match this year 2013 in the other table where a year column in YYYY format.

Comment: @NEWBEE if you are populating a `date` column then maybe what you want is `trunc(ins_dt,'YEAR')` which will make it 00:00:00 on 1st January.

Comment: I am sorry for multiple comments. To make it simple and Clear. I need only 2013 in this field 7/31/2013 11:36:04 PM.  This is my query INS_DT = (select MIN(INS_DT) 
                      from  PROV 
                      WHERE TRIM(BEAU.NO) = TRIM(PROV.NO) 
                      AND BEAU.YEAR = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(prov.INS_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM','YYYY'),'YYYY'))

Comment: Now you are joining it and it has to match `beau.year`. What is that? In your question you are just inserting it.

Comment: Beau is the alias of other table. This statement in used in the where clause  INS_DT = (select MIN(INS_DT) from PROV WHERE TRIM(BEAU.NO) = TRIM(PROV.NO) AND BEAU.YEAR = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(prov.INS_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM','YYYY'),'YYYY'))

Comment: BEAU  
NAME NO    YEAR
CAR        1234        2013
AUTO 4356 2013
PROV   
NO NUMBER  NAME INS_DATE
1234 987         ZZ         7/13/2013
1234 456         ZZ       12/1/2013
RESULT                                                                                                       NAME NO YEAR NUMBER  NAME
CAR        1234  2013 987                 ZZ

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't follow all these comments.

Comment: Above comment is my table and expected result. Below is my full Query 
SELECT * FROM 
BEAU_PROV BEAU
JOIN PROVI PROV 
ON TRIM(BEAU.NPI) = TRIM(PROV.PROV_NPI)
WHERE 
PROV.DW_INS_DT = (select MIN(INS_DT) 
                      from PROVI PROV 
                      WHERE TRIM(BEAU.NPI) = TRIM(PROV.PROV_NPI) 
                      AND BEAU.YEAR = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(INS_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM','YYYY'),'YYYY'))                                                                                    I hope I am not confusing you all